# zero-one law in bipartite random model $G(n,n,p)$

Tags: random-graphs

Consider the binomial random graph model $G(n,p)$ with $0<p<1$. We say that $G(n,p)$ satisfies the Zero-One law if for every first order property $Q$ one has 
$$\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} Pr(G(n,p)\text{ has property }Q) \in \{ 0, 1 \}.$$ 
It has been proved that any fixed $p$, $0 < p < 1$ , and $P(n) = n^{-\alpha}$ where $\alpha$ is an irrational number satisfy in Zero-One law.

Now, Let $G(n, n, p)$ denote the random bipartite graph derived from the complete bipartite graph $K_{n,n}$ where each edge is included independently with probability $p$. Does the random graph $G(n, n, p)$, where here p is fixed number between 0 and 1, obeys $0-1$ law?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, by adaptation of the usual proof.

Let $L$ be the first-order language with a unary predicate $P(x)$ (denoting one of the partitions) and $E(x,y)$ (for edges of the graph, directed from $P$ to its complement). Let $T$ be the $L$-theory consisting of $\forall x,y\,(E(x,y)\to P(x)\land\neg P(y))$, and axioms expressing that for any pair of disjoint finite sets $U$ and $V$ in one partition, there is a node in the other partition connected to every node in $U$, and no node in $V$. Then a straightforward back-and-forth argument shows that $T$ is $\omega$-categorical, hence complete. Moreover, an easy computation shows that each axiom of $T$ holds in $G(n,n,p)$ with probability converging to $1$. Thus, any FO sentence holds with limit probability $1$ if provable in $T$, and limit probability $0$ otherwise.

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not know a lot about  Logic. As I know the proof for the Binomial model is based on a variant of the Ehrenfeucht Game. More precisely:                                                                                            A function p = p(n) satisfies the Zero-One Law if and only iffor 
every t, letting G(n,p(n)), H(m,p(m)) be independently chosen random graphs on  disjoint vértex sets, 
$$\lim_{n,m\to\infty} Pr [Duplicator wins EHR{G(n,p(n)),H(m,p(m)), t]]  = 1 .$$ Now, I am curious to know is there such approach exist for random bipartite graphs? thanks

Comment: It seems to me that reasoning about probabilities in terms of the Ehrenfeucht–Fraïssé game is unnecessarily complicated, nevertheless the underlying combinatorial argument should ultimately be the same.

Comment: You're assuming that p is constant here, the interesting case of the zero-one law is that it tends to zero, so that your axioms do not all hold with probability one (some will, depends on the order of magnitude of p). Still there is 'usually' a zero-one law, except if you deliberately choose p which is in the threshold window of an FO property (what's not trivial is to show that there are few such choices).

Comment: @user36212 The question asks for $p$ constant.

Comment: Sure, but in the question they mention that 0<p<1 constant gives a 0-1 law (as per your proof sketch) _and_ p(n)=n^{-\alpha} with \alpha irrational also does. Though again I think the proof of this goes through easily for bipartite model.

Comment: @user36212 Well yes, the case with nonconstant $p$ is a natural followup question. I am not familiar with the Shelah&Spencer proof, but I would expect it should be adaptable to bipartite graphs.